# Formatting Images in a single page

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to format these two images in one page.I am able to bring
both of them together while comprimising on the clarity.
Is there anyway I can do it in a better way.
Can you please suggest me changes to the LaTeX code.

```
\subsubsection{Block Diagrams}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{design2.png}
\caption{The Overview}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{2.png}
\caption{The Basic}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks

ANupam

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not post such fragments only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

There's no need to use two `figure` environments -- using `\caption` twice for the individual images is more important.

Please don't use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` inside a floating environment -- apply `\centering` instead!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove the demo option for the real document

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{Stuff}
\subsubsection{Block Diagrams}
\blindtext[5]

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{design2.png}
\caption{The Overview}

\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{2.png}
\caption{The Basic}

\end{figure}

\blindtext[5]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You asked for advice on better ways to do it, and I cannot improve Christian Hupfers answer much, but here is a different way of doing it.

This solution uses `wrapfig` to place some figures within the text itself. The text is wrapped around the images. I wouldn't advise on using this too much, though, as it might give the paper a cramped effect. But maybe use one `wrapfigure`with a regular figure, perhaps something like image A and B here.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Example text
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A tiny picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9}
    \caption{A tiny picture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{A tiny picture}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1), but please don't use the `\usepackage{foo1,foo2,foo3}` style -- I know, it's allowed syntax, but as soon as one package has an option that's not supported by others there will be trouble

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Really? Do you have any more information about this? I haven't really heard anything about it, other than when giving options to packages.

Comment: Just try: `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx,tocloft}

\begin{document}

\end{document}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, well, of course. I normally write each packages which don't require options in one `\usepackage`-statement, each package having their own line. Those packages that need options get their own `\usepackage`-statement. I guess it's a matter of style. I like to not repeat my code.

Comment: Of course it's style ... but error - prone. I rather repeat `\usepackage` statements